# Why does Gradle module need direct dependency on another module on which it does not depend on directly?

Tags: gradle, gradle-multi-project-build

I have a multimodule project like below

```
ProjectA
{
    interface IInterfaceA 
    {
        api1();
        api2();
    }
}


ProjectB
{
    class ClassB implements IInterfaceA
    {
        api1();
        api2();
        someStaticFunction();
    }
}
implementation (':ProjectA')


ProjectC
{
    class ClassC
    {
        ClassB.someStaticFunction();   ---> compile error, cannot access IInterfaceA
    }
}
implementation (':ProjectB')
//implementation (':ProjectA') ---> if I add this here, it works
```

Why though ? since project C is not depending directly on any implemetation of ProjectA, why does it still have to add ":ProjectA" as a direct dependency ?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you probably defined `ProjectA` as a dependency of `ProjectB` using `implementation`. This leads to `ProjectA` being accessible in `ProjectB`, *but not in any modules depending on B*.

> **api** – used to make the dependencies explicit and expose them in the classpath. For instance, when implementing a library to be transparent to the library consumers'
> **implementation** – required to compile the production source code and are purely internal. They aren't exposed outside the package

Taken from [this baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-dependency-management#2-types-of-configuration) which outlines the different configuration types of gradle.

Comment: I get the difference between api and implementation. In my case, ProjectC does not depend "directly" on ProjectA. It only depends on projectB, so it should be enough for projectA to be a transitive dependency to it through ProjectB. Atleast that's what I think.

Comment: Yes, BUT it needs to be declared as an `api`. With `implementation`, ProjectC doesn't have access to `ProjectA`.

Comment: I understand that it will work if you either make the 'projectA' as api dependecy to projectB or just add projectA also as a impl dependency to projectC

Comment: My question was, why ? projectC does not directly depend on project A. It only depends on a static function of projectB. 

Another weird behavior I noticed is, if projectC uses a variable (static or instance) of the same class instead of the static function, it works fine without needing projectA as impl dependency to projectC or as api dependency to projectB.

how do you explain that ?

It looks like variable access is fine, method access is not